# sed: replace any number of occurrences of a certain pattern

Tags: sed

Given this input:

```
 "hell -- 'this -- world --is'-- beautiful' --thanks-- we'-- are-- here"
```

I want to replace every '--' in between single quotes with 'X-X-X' using `sed`. It should give the following output:

output: "hell --'this X-X-X world X-X-Xis'-- beautiful' X-X-Xthanks X-X-X we' -- are here"

The number of replacements may be unknown (up to infinity).

Answer (score 13):

You want to use the /g switch at the end to parse more than one substitution per line.

```
sed s/--/X-X-X/g
```

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**

Using your new requirement:

```
sed 's/\o47[^\o47]*\o47/\n&\n/g;:a;s/\(\n\o47[^\n]*\)--/\1X-X-X/;ta;s/\n//g' input file
```

**Edit 2:**

For some versions of `sed` which don't like semicolons:

```
sed -e 's/\o47[^\o47]*\o47/\n&\n/g' -e ':a' -e 's/\(\n\o47[^\n]*\)--/\1X-X-X/' -e 'ta' -e 's/\n//g' inputfile
```

If your `sed` also doesn't support octal escape codes:

```
sed -e "s/'[^']*'/\n&\n/g" -e ':a' -e "s/\(\n'[^\n]*\)--/\1X-X-X/" -e 'ta' -e 's/\n//g' inputfile
```

**Original Answer:**

You should usually use single quotes to surround the `sed` script so you don't have to escape characters which may be special to the shell. Even though it's not necessary in this instance it's a good habit to develop.

```
sed 's/--/X-X-X/g' inputfile
```

or

```
var="hell --this -- world is --beaut--iful"
newvar=$(echo "$var" | sed 's/--/X-X-X/g')
```

Without the `g` modifier, the replacement is performed on the first match on each line of input. When `g` is used, each match on each line of input is replaced. You can also do the replacement for particular matches:

```
$ var="hell --this -- world is --beaut--iful"
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/--/X-X-X/2'
hell --this X-X-X world is --beaut--iful
```

Comment: sorry for putting my question wrong way :
input:
"hell -- 'this -- world --is'-- beautiful' --thanks-- we'-- are-- here"
output:
"hell --'this X-X-X world X-X-Xis'-- beautiful' X-X-Xthanks X-X-X we' -- are here"

Comment: @shiva: Please see my edited answer. Also, please edit your question to show this input instead of the one you originally posted.

Comment: @shiva: What is the specific error message you're getting? What version of `sed` are you using? What is the operating system? Try the new version I've added which separates the parts of the script using `-e`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ echo "hell --this -- world is --beaut--iful" | sed s"/--/X-X-X/g"
hell X-X-Xthis X-X-X world is X-X-XbeautX-X-Xiful
```

The key is the `g` switch: It causes `sed` to replace all occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies 
sorry for putting my question wrong way :
Actually my requirements :
replace every -- inbetween single quote '' remaining untouched
here i am giving input and output
input:
"hell -- 'this -- world --is'-- beautiful' --thanks-- we'-- are-- here"
output:
"hell --'this X-X-X world X-X-Xis'-- beautiful' X-X-Xthanks X-X-X we' -- are here"

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dainel for quick reply 
Sorry for putting my question in wrongway
I posted my question again with almost same title

Thanks

Comment: thanks Daniel
sed 's/\o47[^\o47]*\o47/\n&\n/g;:a;s/\(\n\o47[^\n]*\)--/\1X-X-X/;ta;s/\n//g' input file

but  "this one giving regular expression Error:????????????????"

Comment: @shiva: You replied to the wrong answer. I (Dennis) am the one who posted the answer that seems to be giving you an error. I will reply to your comment in a comment attached to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "     -- hell     -- this ------   world       ---- test"  |\
sed -r 's/[ ]+[-]+[ ]+/ x-x-x /g'
```

Gives:

```
 x-x-x hell x-x-x this x-x-x world x-x-x test
```

The character sequence in brackets is matched for a repeat one or more times by the plus symbol.